# 'overflow-x: scroll' inside a fixed div prevents vertical scrolling on ios

Tags: html, ios, css

It seems that if you have a div with horizontal scroll, inside a div that is positioned fixed, it prevents vertical scrolling on IOS. I.E - if I begin scrolling by placing my finger on the horizontal scrolling div, and try to scroll vertically, nothing happens.

Seems to be fine on my colleagues Andriod device.

I have created a test case, demonstrating the issue here:

http://jsbin.com/jikatugeli/

Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  some content underneath
  <div class="pop-up">
    <p>I'm some other content</p>
    <div class="scrollable">
      <div class="item">hi</div>
      <div class="item">hi</div>
      <div class="item">hi</div>
      <div class="item">hi</div>
      <div class="item">hi</div>
      <div class="item">hi</div>
      <div class="item">hi</div>
      <div class="item">hi</div>
      <div class="item">hi</div>
      <div class="item">hi</div>
      <div class="item">hi</div>
    </div>
    <div class="somemoretext">
      hello there, I am some text to make things scrollable
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css

```
p {
  font-size:22px;
}

.item {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
    height:60px;
  font-size:78px;
}

.scrollable {
  width:350px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.pop-up {
  position:fixed;
  height:300px;
  background:red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  z-index:9999;
}

.somemoretext {
  padding-top:600px;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have tried your demo on my iPad 2, and iPhone 7, and I can't find any problem.

Comment: I have an iphone 7 too. I'll try and be more specific about the problem. Notice that if you place your finger on the red and try to scroll up and down it works fine. However, if you begin by placing your fingers on the words saying 'hi hi hi hi hi' (the horizontal scrolling div) you cant scroll up and down. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The below css fixes your issue

```
html,body{height:100%}
body{background:red}
p {
  font-size:22px;
}

.item {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
    height:60px;
  font-size:78px;
}

.scrollable {
  width:350px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidde;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.pop-up {
  position:fixed;
  height:300px;
  background:blue;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  z-index:9999;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.somemoretext {
  padding-top:600px;
}
```

The lines containing -webkit- are the key to make the scrolling work in Safari.
In the .pop-up DIV you need overflow-y: scroll and –webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch to force the scrolling.  In .scrollableyou need –webkit-transform: tranzlateZ(0); to move the actual html content up and down, other wise the DIV will scroll but the overflowing content will NOT show.

Comment: Perfect! Works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In my case I also had to add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the body element since it was also using overflow-x:hidden .
Hope it will save some time for someone.

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the body styles resolved this for me.

Comment: I had a list that was scrolling for Chrome Desktop / Android, but not iOS. Adding this to the body tag made it work.

Thanks!