# Can only scroll page with two fingers on iOS

Tags: css, ios, safari

We have a strange bug in our application where sometimes you can only scroll tall pages with two fingers. If trying to scroll with one finger the page doesn't move, and we just can't seem to find a solution to it. This only appears in iOS and in both Safari & Chrome. Any advice would be helpful!

Edit: Just to be clear, the desired outcome is to be able to scroll with one finger and NOT two fingers!

Comment: You need to provide an example ... you've essentially said "We have (probably a css) problem - how can we fix it?"

Comment: It's a complex application with nested microfrontends and custom elements so there's a lot of css affecting it and it wouldn't say much to copy all that in. Thought someone might have a general tip on what css to e.g. put on the html and body-elements to have this not appearing.

Answer (score 2):

We finally found the root cause of this issue which was a failed old script that applied a ‘touchmove’-event listener, that somehow blocked touch events, that was not removed later due to the script failing.

Comment: Could you please provide more info or possibly a code example? I am currently facing the same issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is an intentional behaviour. iOS is trying to prevent accidental one-finger scrolling in containers, forcing users to be explicit in their expected scrolling. We had the same issue on our website and I just found out about this [on this website](https://wyattlecadre.wordpress.com/2010/11/20/ios-quick-tip-two-finger-scrolling/).

A possible solution (that I will confirm shortly) can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/607758/Scrollable-div-which-allows-single-finger-scrollin) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681251/overflow-x-scroll-inside-a-fixed-div-prevents-vertical-scrolling-on-ios).

Let me know if that works for you.