# Scrolling a div is limited to two fingers on iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, reactjs, react-tsx

#### The problem

I have a frustrating bug on my app, specifically on iOS devices. A specific div only allows scrolling with two fingers. I tried following the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72633216/can-only-scroll-page-with-two-fingers-on-ios) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681251/overflow-x-scroll-inside-a-fixed-div-prevents-vertical-scrolling-on-ios). For some reason, they don't seem to work.

The div I am trying to make scrollable is the one with className formContent.

#### Code

React Component:

```
 <DialogBackdrop {...props} className={styles.backdrop}>
      <ReakitDialog className={classNames(className, styles.dialog)} {...props}>
        <DialogTitle>
          <CloseDialog handleClose={handleClose} />
          {header}
        </DialogTitle>
        <div className={styles.formContent}>
          <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            innerRef={formRef}
            enableReinitialize={true}
          >
            <Form>
              {children}
            </Form>
          </Formik>
        </div>
        {props.variant !== "info" &&
          <DialogActions>
            <DialogFooter
              variant={props.variant}
              onClose={handleClose}
              onSubmit={saveInputs}
              loading={loading}
              submitLabel={submitLabel}
              cancelLabel={cancelLabel} />
          </DialogActions>}
      </ReakitDialog>
    </DialogBackdrop >
```

SCSS:

```
.backdrop {
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: rgba(tokens.$color-whisper, 0.95);

  @include theme.media-desktop-up {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    grid-template-columns: 40rem;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;
    padding-inline: tokens.$spacing-xxx-small;
    grid-template-rows: tokens.$spacing-x-large minmax(min-content, auto) tokens.$spacing-xx-large;

    &:before {
      content: '';
      height: tokens.$spacing-xx-large;
    }

    &:after {
      content: '';
      height: tokens.$spacing-x-large;
    }
  }
}

.dialog {
  width: 100%;
  margin-inline: auto;
  background-color: tokens.$color-white;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  @include theme.media-tablet-down {

    height: 100%;
  }

  @include theme.media-desktop-up {
    max-width: 40rem;
    min-height: 307px;
    max-height: 40rem;
    border-radius: tokens.$radius-large;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 60px -20px tokens.$color-silver,
      0 12px 12px -12px tokens.$color-palladium,
      0 0 0 1px tokens.$color-silver;
  }
}

.title {

  background-color: tokens.$color-white;
  margin-block-start: tokens.$spacing-medium;
  margin-block-end: tokens.$spacing-small;
  @include theme.media-desktop-up {
    padding-inline: tokens.$spacing-xx-large;
  }

  @include theme.media-tablet-down {
    padding: tokens.$spacing-small;
  }
}


.formContent {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  @include theme.media-desktop-up {
    padding-inline: tokens.$spacing-xx-large;
  }

  @include theme.media-tablet-down {
    padding-inline: tokens.$spacing-small;
  }
}
```

Thank you